# Statement True Even if Time is Different

Tags: bash

I've been working on a bash script to change my background depending on the time of day but I can't figure out why the background is always changed to dawn even if the time is Noon.

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date "+%H")
DawnNum=$(seq -s " -o " 5 9)
DayNum=$(seq -s " -o " 10 17)
DuskNum=$(seq -s " -o " 18 22)
NightNum=$(seq -s " -o " 23 24)
NightNumCont=$(seq -s " -o " 0 4)

if
    [ -e ~/.cache/weather.txt ] ;
then
    rm ~/.cache/weather.txt ;
else
    echo "Cache is clean." ;
fi

curl -o ~/.cache/weather.txt -s "https://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2470169&u=f" ;

cat ~/.cache/weather.txt | grep Rain -n | grep 29 || cat ~/.cache/weather.txt | grep Snow -n | grep 29 ;
current=$?

if
    [ "$current" -eq 0 ] && [ "$date" -eq $DawnNum -o $DayNum ] ; then
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/Pictures/Google Now/mountains-stormday.png" ;
elif
    [ "$current" -eq 0 ] && [ "$date" -eq $DuskNum -o $NightNum ] ; then
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/Pictures/Google Now/mountains-stormnight.png" ;
elif
    [ "$current" -ne 0 ] && [ "$date" -eq $DawnNum ] ; then
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/Pictures/Google Now/mountainsdawn.png" ;
elif
    [ "$current" -ne 0 ] && [ "$date" -eq $DayNum ] ; then
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/Pictures/Google Now/mountainsday.png" ;
elif
    [ "$current" -ne 0 ] && [ "$date" -eq $DuskNum ] ; then
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/Pictures/Google Now/mountainsdusk.png" ;
elif
    [ "$current" -ne 0 ] && [ "$date" -eq $NightNum ] ; then
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/Pictures/Google Now/mountainsnight.png" ;
else
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/Pictures/Google Now/sanfranciscodawn.png" ;
fi

exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend simplifying your logic and reducing repetition in your code. As you are using bash and working with integers, you can use `(( ))` numerical tests to determine what time range you are within. This kind of test doesn't require you to use `$` variable names and expresses your meaning a little more clearly:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date "+%H")
dawn_start=5
day_start=10
dusk_start=18
night_start=23

# ...

current=$?
if [[ "$current" == 0 ]]; then 
    if (( date >= dawn_start )) && (( date < dusk_start )); then
        uri="mountains-stormday.png"
    else
        uri="mountains-stormnight.png"
    fi
else
    if (( date >= dawn_start )) && (( date < day_start )); then
        uri="mountainsdawn.png"
    elif (( date >= day_start )) && (( date < dusk_start )); then
        uri="mountainsday.png"
    elif (( date >= dusk_start )) && (( date < night_start )); then
        uri="mountainsdusk.png"
    elif (( date >= night_start )) || (( date < dawn_start )); then
        uri="mountainsnight.png"
    fi
fi

# catch-all, if $uri hasn't been set
[[ -z "$uri" ]] && uri="sanfranciscodawn.png"

dir="file:///home/user/Pictures/Google Now"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri "$dir/$uri"
```

Comment: ...and, well, `[[ ]]` prevents string-splitting and glob expansion (albeit doing pattern-matching when the right-hand side of some comparisons are unquoted, but neither `=` or `=~` is in use here), so double-quotes aren't necessary there regardless.

Comment: That said, `[[ $foo < $bar ]]` does comparison of the ASCII characters for lexical sort order; are you sure that's what's needed here, not `(( foo < bar ))` (which is a numerical sort)?

Comment: @Charles I've made some changes, as always I appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you expect:

```
[ "$date" -eq $DawnNum -o $DayNum ]
```

The problem is that `-eq` binds more tightly than `-o`.

A simpler test that might do what you are aiming for is:

```
[ "$date" -ge 5 ] && [ "$date" -le 17 ]
```